# Ruby: how to use/turn multi-word strings into symbols

Tags: ruby, hash, key, symbols

Most hash keys are single word names. Let's use movie names and ratings as an example. That's easy to make a symbol:

`my_hash = { Ferris_Bueller: 5}`

What if I don't want to use an underscore in my key name, but need that string as a symbol?
I thought of doing this, but it doesn't work:

`my_hash = { "Ferris Bueller": 5}`

The issue is, I'm trying to prompt the user to name a movie, rate it, then add those values as a key/value pair in `my_hash`. People will input two-word movies normally, without the underscore. How do I get that key to store in the hash as a symbol? I.e.:

`puts "Name a movie:"
 name = gets.chomp
 puts "Rate it 1-5:"
 rating = gets.chomp
 my_hash[name.to_sym] = rating`

The user types a two-word movie, such as `Robo Cop`. Why wont this work?

Comment: `Why wont this work?` It does work...

Comment: Unbelievable. I was just using repl.it and it gave me an error on this. Tried again and it works. I just don't get it. Thank you August.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a multi-word symbol using this notation:

```
:"multi word symbol" => value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use .gsub! to convert the _ to a space and then .gsub! again to convert it back. This way the code is still registered but the user never sees the underscore. Here's an example:

```
movies = {
The_Raven: 4,
I_Robot: 3
}

puts "Howdy, please select one of the following."
choice = gets.chomp
case choice
when "update"
puts "Please select which movie you'd like to update."
title = gets.chomp
title.gsub!(/ /, "_")
#By doing this, the user can type 'The Raven' and Ruby will be able to
#register it as a title in your movies hash.
if
    movies[title.to_sym].nil?
    puts "That movie doesn't exist in our inventory!"
else 
    puts "What would you like to change the rating to? (Rating must be 1 - 5)"
    rating = gets.chomp
    movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
    title.gsub!(/_/, " ")
#Then you convert it back from an underscore to a space. This way Ruby 
#will display to the user the title without underscores. 
    puts "#{title} has been updated with a new rating of #{rating}."
end`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get that working you might need to use hash rockets actually...

```
my_hash = { :"Ferris Bueller" => 5}
```

Comment: I tried this as well, and indeed, it does work. The original code I used works as well. Must have been a glitch in the repl.it engine or something. I'm learning to refresh a lot.